# str argument only functioning when submitted via single quotes as opposed to assigned variable

Tags: python, git

I am using [Libsaas](http://docs.libsaas.net/en/latest/generated/github/) to pull a [specific commit via sha](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit)

This python function pulls sha at HEAD

```
sha_in_memory = StringIO()

def get_sha():
    p1 = Popen(["git", "rev-parse", "HEAD"], stdout = PIPE)
    sha = p1.communicate()[0]
    print ("the sha is: %s" % sha)
    p1.stdout.close()
    sha_in_memory.write(sha)
    # sha = local("git rev-parse HEAD")
    sha_in_file = open('shafile.txt', 'w')
    sha_in_file.write(sha)
    sha_in_file.close()
```

This redundant file and write to memory is a result of me trying various solutions.

Next I am reading the sha into a variable named 'value'

```
with open('shafile.txt', 'r') as f:
        value = f.read()
```

value is submitted as the sha arg for the [libsaas commit function](http://docs.libsaas.net/en/latest/generated/github/#github.organizations.OrganizationRepo.commit)

```
print ("it still is :%s" % value) #sanity check it is returning the expected sha hash
    print  repo.commit(value).get()
```

When run on the command line the following response is returned

```
it still is :137993b2f8408cbb66b82dd67c85e610c4f83874

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "remote_git_tasks.py", line 48, in <module>
    print  repo.commit(value).get()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libsaas/services/base.py", line 95, in wrapped
    return current.process(request, parser)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libsaas/executors/urllib2_executor.py", line 80, in __call__
    return parser(body, resp.code, headers)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libsaas/parsers.py", line 16, in parse_json
    raise http.HTTPError(body, code, headers)
libsaas.http.HTTPError: <HTTPError code 404>
```

I have made sure it is a str I am returning using

```
print type(value) is str
```

This returns 'True'

When I submit the argument by simply placing the sha in quotes it works, returning the expected JSON from the api.

```
print  repo.commit('137993b2f8408cbb66b82dd67c85e610c4f83874').get()
```

I have tried a variety of conversions and have even rewritten the function to make use of Fabric's local() function and again Subprocess' Popen.  In each case when I use the defined variable it does not work, when I submit the sha in '' works.

Any clarity would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at the actual value you're getting from the file?  It might have a newline at the end or something like that.  The blank line in your output also suggests an extra newline.  Try using `%r` instead of `%s` in your `print` to print the `repr` instead of the `str` of your string; this will show any extra `\n` or the like.

Comment: I agree with @BrenBarn that there may be whitespace secretly messing things up. Try `print ("it still is :%s" % repr(value))`, and see if there's a \r at the end or something.

Comment: try to add `value.strip()` to get rid of any whitespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read from a file, you usually get a trailing newline character. Try stripping that off first:

```
with open('shafile.txt', 'r') as f:
    value = f.read().strip()
```

Comment: Oh Joy!  .strip() worked!    I actually backed off the use of making a file since the StringIO implementation is cleaner. Thank you!